# getLoginStatusURL() migrate to OAuth2

Tags: php, sdk, oauth-2.0, facebook-php-sdk

When attempting to call `getLoginStatusURL()`. I get the message:

```
Please migrate to OAuth2 and use the new /dialog/oauth endpoint. extern/login_status.php is no longer available.
```

Answer (score 2):

The `getLoginStatusUrl` method in the SDK has not been kept up-to-date with the rest of the platform (the SDK actually doesn't know how to handle the response), and unfortunately, it was referring to a url deprecated a long time ago.

What you want instead, is to use the `getLoginUrl` method and pass in `array('display' => 'none')` - this will give you the expected result.

```
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('display' => 'none'));
```

Comment: I'm not able to get the expected result from this. `getLoginStatusUrl` was acting like a redirect hub. you gave it 3 params (aside from api_key & session_version) that would redirect to the given url depending on the results.

no_session = redirect_url
no_user = redirect_url2
ok_session = redirect_url3

so without the user seeing any login or allow screen, I was able to direct the user to where they needed to be depending on what state they were in. `getLoginUrl` only gives me the url to dialog/oauth which displays auth to the user before proceeding to the single redirect_uri that is defined.

Comment: @Sheac, the params you mention were part of the pre-oauth flows and has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your app is set to pick up the code parameter from the Query String rather than the uri_fragment - this can be set on facebook apps page apps>settings>permissions.

That did it for me using $facebook->getLoginUrl() to provide the login URL

Comment: I dont seem to have an opportunity to comment on the original question so had no alternative - i can comment on your comment though

Comment: Well, my suggestion would be removing this answer completely, or you risk getting down-voted more

Comment: Updated to actually answer the question now